# Ruby threads: how to join threads from different places so that they are concurrent?

Tags: ruby, multithreading

```
a = Thread.new { 5.times { |i| p i; sleep 0.1 } }
a.join
p 'a'

b = Thread.new { 5.times { |k| p k; sleep 0.1 } }
b.join
p 'b'
```

This will print out **01234a01234b**. What I want it to print out is: **001122334a4b**.
`p 'b'` and `p 'a'` must both be outside of threads. They must execute after corresponding thread is finished. **a** and **b** threads must execute concurrently.

How can it be done?

Comment: "They must execute after corresponding thread is finished" - just put them at the end of thread bodies then, no?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, actually yes, first I decided it's not possible in my case but I looked at it again and see that it is. This would solve one problem.

Comment: @lakesare if your question has been resolved, please select an answer below as the "accepted answer" (green checkmark).

Comment: @HunterStevens, yep, thanks for reminding me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if you change when you join, you'll get pretty close.

```
a = Thread.new { 5.times { |i| p i; sleep 0.1 } }
b = Thread.new { 5.times { |k| p k; sleep 0.1 } }
a.join
b.join
p 'a'
p 'b'
```

But this behavior is not guaranteed.  Without some kind of thread synchronization, you'll get whatever the scheduler wants you to get.  Do you **always** want that **exact** ordering?

Comment: it's important to place a.join after `a thread block` and b.join after `b thread block` in my application. and `p 'a'` must fire exactly when `a block` is finished, because its value is produced in a thread. actually here is my code if it'll be clearer what I'm trying to achieve: https://github.com/lakesare/credits/blob/master/credits.rb

Comment: If the joins have to occur where they do in your example, I don't believe it's possible to do what you want.

Comment: yes, it looks like it, or I should change my architecture completely.

Comment: @lakesare it sounds like you don't understand the purpose of `join`: it **blocks the main thread** until the joined thread finishes. There is simply no way to have `b` run concurrently with `a` if you join `a` before creating `b`.

Comment: @Max, that's true, I'm very confused about them (in my example they exists only so that errors are produced if something goes wrong in a thread). so joins must follow one after another to execute concurrently?

Comment: They need to be as close as possible to each other to have the possibility of concurrency.  With threads unless you use some synchronization, you get what the scheduler decides to do.  The joins just say "all these threads I just made, wait til they're done".